# CameraPreview not shown at beginning, but after hot reload

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When this app is launched it displays just the CircularProgressIndicator and never the camera stream. However if a hot reload is triggered the CameraPreview is shown, but only then. Tested this on two different Android devices.

Is this some kind of race condition with the Future? What did I miss out?

Code attached:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: CameraTestHome()));
}

class CameraTestHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraTestHomeState createState() {
    return _CameraTestHomeState();
  }
}

class _CameraTestHomeState extends State<CameraTestHome> {
  CameraController _cameraController;
  Future<void> _initializeCameraControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeCamera();
  }

  void _initializeCamera() async {
    CameraDescription cameraDescription =
        await getCamera(CameraLensDirection.front);

    _cameraController = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );

    _initializeCameraControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();
    _initializeCameraControllerFuture
        .then((_) => _cameraController.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
              // Some Image Processing to be inserted.
            }));
  }

  Future<CameraDescription> getCamera(CameraLensDirection direction) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
            (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == direction,
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('CameraTest')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeCameraControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Debug Log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on A0001 in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
I/CameraManagerGlobal(24135): Connecting to camera service
W/LegacyMetadataMapper(24135): mapScalerStreamConfigs - failed to find any preview size matching JPEG aspect ratio 1.3487179
I/CameraManager(24135): Using legacy camera HAL.
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-1(24135): Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
D/Camera  (24135): app passed NULL surface
I/RequestThread-1(24135): configureOutputs - set take picture size to 2592x1944
W/Adreno-EGL(24135): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
W/Adreno-EGL(24135): <qeglDrvAPI_eglQueryContext:4370>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/RequestQueue(24135): Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
I/RequestQueue(24135): Repeating capture request cancelled.
I/Gralloc2(24135): Adding additional valid usage bits: 0x2200000
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-1(24135): Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/Camera  (24135): app passed NULL surface
W/Adreno-EGL(24135): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
W/Adreno-EGL(24135): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:607>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
W/Adreno-EGL(24135): <qeglDrvAPI_eglQueryContext:4370>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
W/game.blink_gam(24135): Long monitor contention with owner main (24135) at void android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(android.hardware.camera2.params.InputConfiguration, java.util.List, android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession$StateCallback, java.util.concurrent.Executor, int, android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest)(CameraDeviceImpl.java:636) waiters=0 in void android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onCaptureStarted(android.hardware.camera2.impl.CaptureResultExtras, long) for 337ms
I/RequestQueue(24135): Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
W/LegacyRequestMapper(24135): convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
I/CameraDeviceState(24135): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
W/System  (24135): A resource failed to call release.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
D/vndksupport(24135): Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8974.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
I/game.blink_gam(24135): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1200(144KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(32MB) LOS objects, 49% free, 22MB/44MB, paused 8.573ms total 52.028ms
I/game.blink_gam(24135): Background concurrent copying GC freed 1216(143KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(32MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 22MB/44MB, paused 5.317ms total 39.770ms
Application finished.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the FutureBuilder relies on _initializeCameraControllerFuture which is not initialized yet when build() is called.
Simply initializing _initializeCameraControllerFuture before solves the problem.